# Commands are ignored in telebot when my program is waiting for an user input through a message handler

Tags: python, function, import, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from telebot.types import Message
from createuser import registration_conversation
from key import bot


# link to database
registered_users = set()

# Handler for the /start commands


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: Message):
    user_id = message.chat.id

    if user_id in registered_users:
        # User is already registered, send menu options
        send_menu(message)
    else:
        registration_conversation(message)


# Registration conversation


def send_menu(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Edit Profile")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("View Others")
    markup.add(item1, item2)

    bot.send_message(
        user_id, "Welcome to the main menu. Please choose an option:", reply_markup=markup)

# Handler for menu option 1: Edit Profile


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'Edit Profile')
def edit_profile(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    # Add your logic for editing the profile here
    bot.send_message(
        user_id, "You selected 'Edit Profile'. Add your logic here.")

# Handler for menu option 2: View Others


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'View Others')
def view_others(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    # Add your logic for viewing others here
    bot.send_message(
        user_id, "You selected 'View Others'. Add your logic here.")


# Start the bot
print("Polling")
bot.polling()
import sqlite3
import telebot
from telebot import types
from telebot.types import Message
from key import bot
import os

DATABASE_FILE = 'dating.db'

SAVE_FOLDER = 'downloads'


def save_image_files(user_id: int, photos):
    for photo in photos[0]:
        i = 0
        file_id = photo.file_id
        file_info = bot.get_file(file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

        file_path = os.path.join(SAVE_FOLDER, f"{user_id}_photo_{i}.jpg")
        i = i + 1
        # Save the file to the specified path
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(downloaded_file)

    print(f"All {len(photos)} profile pictures saved for user {user_id}.")


def create_user_table():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_FILE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            name TEXT NOT NULL,
            age INTEGER,
            gender TEXT,
            city INTEGER,
        )
    ''')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def add_user(name, age, gender, city):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_FILE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        INSERT INTO users (name, age, gender, city)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    ''', (name, age, gender, city))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print("User added successfully!")


users_in_conversation = set()


# def check_for_command(message: Message):
#     user_id = message.from_user.id

#     if message.text == '/start':
#         users_in_conversation.remove(user_id)
#         return True
#     else:
#         return False


def registration_conversation(message: Message):

    user_info = {
        "NAME": None,
        "AGE": None,
        "GENDER": None,
        "LOCATION": None
    }
    user_id = message.from_user.id

    if user_id in users_in_conversation:
        return None
    else:
        users_in_conversation.add(user_id)

    chat_id = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "Welcome! Let's start the registration process.")
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "What is your Name.")

    bot.register_next_step_handler(
        message,  process_name_step, user_info)
    


def process_name_step(message: Message, user_info):

    try:
        user_id = message.chat.id
        user_info['NAME'] = message.text
        print(user_info)
        message = bot.send_message(user_id, 'How old are you?')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_age_step, user_info)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops something went wrong')


def process_age_step(message: Message, user_info):
    try:
        user_id = message.chat.id
        age = message.text
        if not age.isdigit():
            message = bot.send_message(
                user_id, 'Age should be a number. How old are you?')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(
                message, process_age_step, user_info)
            return

        user_info['AGE'] = age
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
        markup.add('Male', 'Female')
        message = bot.send_message(
            user_id, 'What is your gender', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_sex_step, user_info)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops something went wrong')


def process_sex_step(message: Message, user_info):
    try:
        user_id = message.chat.id
        sex = message.text
        print(sex)
        if (sex == 'Male') or (sex == 'Female'):
            user_info['GENDER'] = sex
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
                resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
            share_location_button = types.KeyboardButton(
                "Share Location", request_location=True)
            markup.add(share_location_button)
            message = bot.send_message(
                user_id, 'What is Your Location', reply_markup=markup)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(
                message, process_location_step, user_info)
        else:
            # retry
            None
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops something went wrong')


def process_location_step(message: Message, user_info):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        # location = message.location
        location = 120
        if location:
            user_info['LOCATION'] = location
            print(user_info)
            name, age, gender, location = user_info.values()
            add_user(name, age, gender, location)
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
                resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
            share_location_button = types.KeyboardButton(
                "Share Image")
            markup.add(share_location_button)
            message = bot.send_message(
                chat_id, 'Please Send An Image', reply_markup=markup)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_image_step)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops something went wrong')


def process_image_step(message: Message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        typePhoto = message.text
        if (typePhoto == 'Share Image'):
            photos = bot.get_user_profile_photos(user_id)
            if photos.photos:
                save_image_files(user_id, photos.photos)

                bot.send_message(
                    chat_id, "Profile picture processed. You can save or display it.")
                users_in_conversation.remove(user_id)
            else:
                bot.send_message(chat_id, "No Profile Picture Found Try Again")
                bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_image_step)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops something went wrong')
```

My commands are ignored for example when I am at the stage of when my bot asks for my name and instead I provide /start instead of restarting the command my bot registers /start as my NAME in userinfo.

I tried creating an additional function to check for commands but that just causes a circular import.I want my program to understand when a command is being taken place rather than a user input or a way to resolve the imports so my program does not have an issue of being in a circular import.

My Start Function is In Main.py
While the rest in CreateUser.py

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).